# Kubernetes distributed filesystem

Tags: hadoop, kubernetes, filesystems

Well, my company is considering to move from Hadoop to Kubernetes. We can find solutions in Kubernetes for tools such as cassandra, sparks, etc. So the last problem for us is how to store massive amount of files in Kubernetes, saying 1 PB. FYI, we DO NOT want to use online storage services such as S3.

As far as I know, HDFS is merely used in Kubernetes and there are a few replacement products such as Torus and Quobyte. So my question is, any recommendation for the filesystem on Kubernetes? Or any better solution?

Many thanks.

Comment: These are two completely different technologies with completely different uses. Hadoop is a distributed data processing framework, Kubernetes is a container orchestration tool. It's like comparing apples and elephants.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *Hadoop Compatible* FileSystem such as Ceph or Minio. Both of which offer S3-compatible REST APIs for reading and writing. In Kubernetes, Ceph can be deployed using the [Rook](https://rook.io/) project.

But overall, running HDFS in Kubernetes would require stateful services like the NameNode, and DataNodes with proper affinity and network rules in place. The [Hadoop Ozone](https://hadoop.apache.org/ozone/) project is a realization that object storage is more common for microservice workloads than HDFS block storage as reasonably trying to analyze PB of data using distributed microservices wasn't feasible. (I'm only speculating)

The alternative is to [use Docker support in Hadoop & YARN 3.x](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-operating-system/content/run_docker_containers_on_yarn.html)